# Don't know how to test this asyn function with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, ajax, testing, jasmine, bdd

```
asynFn(url, callback)
```

This function takes a url and fires some xhr requests, then uses `callback(result)` to send back processed result. How should I test it?

(I've run the `asynFn` directly in Chrome and it worked fine.)

I tried to use `jasmine-ajax` to stub the request, but the `expect` did't work.

```
describe('a test', function() {
  var callback

  beforeAll(function() {
    jasmine.Ajax.install()

    jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest('fake/path1').andReturn({
      status: 200,
      contentType: 'text/plain',
      responseText: 'yay'
    })

    jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest('fake/path2').andReturn({
      status: 200,
      contentType: 'text/plain',
      responseText: 'yay2'
    })

    // ...
  })

  afterAll(function() {
    jasmine.Ajax.uninstall()
  })

  beforeEach(function() {
    callback = jasmine.createSpy('sendResponse')
  })

  it('a spec', function() {

    asynFn('input string', callback)

    expect(jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent().url).toBe('fake/path2')
    expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalled() // faild
  })
})
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please post the code under test and use semicolons!

Comment: @Sonata Oh sorry. Because I just want to know how to test this kind of function. So I think it's unnecessary to post everything up here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that **asynFn** is **asynchronous** and the callback y called after the expect sentence is executed.

Think you test like a history.

- Subject Under Testing (describe)
- When asynFn is executed (beforeEach)
- Then: A method or callback should be called (it)

Change your code to:

```
  beforeEach(function() {  
    callback = jasmine.createSpy('sendResponse');  
    asynFn('input string', callback);  
  });

 afterEach(function() {
    callback = null;
 });

  it('a spec', function() {
    expect(jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent().url).toBe('fake/path2')
    expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalled() // faild
  })
```

if The first doesn't work, try this:

```
 beforeEach(function(done) {  
      callback = jasmine.createSpy('sendResponse');  
      asynFn('input string', function() {
          callback();
          done(); //<-- This tells jasmine tha async beforeEach is finished
      });  
  });
```

Comment: I think this means "run `asynFn` before each spec". How does it make sure that the asynchronous `callback` is called before the spec?.

Comment: Nice. That's how I just fixed it. I was using `done()` the wrong way. Thanks! Accepted. :D